# How to verify whether my xcframework generates the arm64 simulator slice correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcframework

I have a framework which is already being used by client applications. I am generating the framework on an intel based mac. I am also generating arm64 simulator arch for the framework. How do i verify that this arch is generated correctly without access to the new apple silicon mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xcrun vtool -arch arm64 -show` to check, for example:

```
xcrun vtool -arch arm64 -show GoogleMaps.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps

Load command 2
      cmd LC_BUILD_VERSION
  cmdsize 32
 platform IOSSIMULATOR
    minos 13.0
      sdk 15.5
   ntools 1
     tool LD
  version 764.0
```

You can see the `IOSSIMULATOR` platform

Answer (score -1):

The `info.plist` in the xcframework will contain the supported architectures. But you can also run the `lipo -detailed_info` command in the binary inside  the .framework.

For example:

```
lipo -detailed_info FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics
 
Fat header in: FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics
fat_magic 0xcafebabe
nfat_arch 3
architecture i386
    cputype CPU_TYPE_I386
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_I386_ALL
    capabilities 0x0
    offset 68
    size 105904
    align 2^2 (4)
architecture x86_64
    cputype CPU_TYPE_X86_64
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_X86_64_ALL
    capabilities 0x0
    offset 105976
    size 110848
    align 2^3 (8)
architecture arm64
    cputype CPU_TYPE_ARM64
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM64_ALL
    capabilities 0x0
    offset 216824
    size 135008
    align 2^3 (8)
```